# How to share a data between child and parent component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components (Table component & User component) in my react app. I have several users data in a table in my one component. I need to pass a user id from the Table component to the User component when click on a button. The problem is when I call the property from the table component, it appears **`this.props.onClick is not a function`** error in console. How can I solve this?

Table component:

```
class EnhancedTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userID: 10
    };
    this.sendUserId = this.sendUserId.bind(this);
  }

  sendUserId() {
    this.props.onClick(this.state.userID);
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <button onClick={this.sendUserId}>
           <BorderColorIcon className="action margin-r" />
       </button>
    )
  }
}
```

User component:

```
Import EnhancedTable from './EnhancedTable';

class Users extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userID: 5
    };
    this.onFillForm = this.onFillForm.bind(this);
   }

  onFillForm(idd) {
    this.setState({
      userID : idd
    })
  }

  render() {
     return(
         <span onClick = {this.onFillForm} className="mainUserDivTitle">{this.state.userID}</span>
     )
   }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use EnhancedTable component?

Comment: Can you share the complete code ?

Comment: @EhssanMajdabadi I import it in User component. I updated the code now

Comment: @UtsavPatel I'll try

Comment: What is the relation between EnhancedComponent and Users

Comment: May be you need to use `EnhancedTable` in place of `span` in your return inside render ?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I show EnhancedTable inside the User component

Comment: Importing it is fine. the solution depends on whether  Enhanced component is rendered in the hierarchy of Users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `<EnhancedTable />` instead of `<span />`

In the User component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import EnhancedTable from './EnhancedTable';

class Users extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userID: 5
    };
    this.onFillForm = this.onFillForm.bind(this);
   }

  onFillForm(idd) {
    this.setState({
      userID : idd
    })
  }

  render() {
     return(
         <>
           <div className="mainUserDivTitle">{this.state.userID}</div>
           <EnhancedTable onClick={this.onFillForm} />
         </>
     )
   }
}

export default Users;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assumption: EnhancedTable is child component and User is parent component.

Problem with your code: you have not called Child component, hence EnhancedTable is not getting `this.props.onClick`.

You need to call EnhancedTable like this:

```
<EnhancedTable onClick = {this.onFillForm} />
```